# How to delete a particuar row when clicking on a button?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have searched in google many times but couldn't find exactly what I am looking for.
I have a custom cell in my table view, where I have three labels and a delete button. Now I want to delete the particular row where I am clicking the delete button. So, I just want to know what will be the code to write in the ibAction method of the delete button. Thanks in advance.

This is my ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "detailObject.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end


@implementation ViewController


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.arrPeopleDetail = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
}

- (IBAction)submitButton:(id)sender {
    if ([self.phoneTextField.text isEqualToString:@""] && [self.addressTextField.text isEqualToString:@""] && [self.phoneTextField.text isEqualToString:@""] ) {
        UIAlertView *alrt = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Please Fillup The Above Fields" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alrt show];
    }
    else if ([self.nameTextField.text isEqualToString:@""]) {
        UIAlertView *alrt_name = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Plaeas Enter Name" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:nil ];
        [alrt_name show];
    }
    else if ([self.addressTextField.text isEqualToString:@""]) {
        UIAlertView *alrt_address = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Please Enter Address" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alrt_address show];
    }
    else if ([self.phoneTextField.text isEqualToString:@""]) {
        UIAlertView *alrt_phoneNumber = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Please Enter Phone Number" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alrt_phoneNumber show];
    }
    else
    {
        detailObject *peopleDetail = [[detailObject alloc] init];
        peopleDetail.strPeopleName = self.nameTextField.text;
        peopleDetail.strPeopleAddress = self.addressTextField.text;
        peopleDetail.strPeoplePhoneNumber = self.phoneTextField.text;

        [self.arrPeopleDetail addObject:peopleDetail];

        self.nameTextField.text = @"";
        self.addressTextField.text = @"";
        self.phoneTextField.text = @"";
    }
    [self.detailTable reloadData];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell1"];

    UILabel *lbl1 = (UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1];
    lbl1.text = [[self.arrPeopleDetail objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"strPeopleName"];

    UILabel *lbl2 = (UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:2];
    lbl2.text = [[self.arrPeopleDetail objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"strPeopleAddress"];

    UILabel *lbl3 = (UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:3];
    lbl3.text = [[self.arrPeopleDetail objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"strPeoplePhoneNumber"];

    return cell;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return [self.arrPeopleDetail count];
}


- (IBAction)deleteButtonTapped:(id)sender {
    [self.arrPeopleDetail removeLastObject];
    [self.detailTable reloadData];
}

@end
```

Comment: Where is your delete button placed? in Table view cell?

Comment: Yes, the delete button is placed in my table view cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern is usually like this:

```
-(void)deleteButtonTapped:(id)sender
{
    // ------------------------------------------------
    // Sender is your button
    //
    // We're finding the coordinate of 
    // where we tap on the screen, relative
    // to our tableView
    // ------------------------------------------------
    CGPoint touchPoint = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.tableView];

    // ------------------------------------------------
    // Now we use this coordinate to find 
    // the row where we tap on our tableView.
    // ------------------------------------------------
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:touchPoint];

    // ------------------------------------------------
    // now we have the table row (indexPath.row) 
    // we can use it to delete from our data source
    // ------------------------------------------------

    [self.arrItems removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    // refresh inteface after updating data source
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: I haven't understood what is the first two lines are doing, but the code is working exactly what I was looking for. Thanks Zhang. :)

Comment: I added explanation for what the first two lines of code do.

Comment: This is cleaner solution than mine.

Answer (score 0):

First, `deleteButtonTapped:` needs to know which index of cell's delete button is pressed. Set the button's tag at `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. For example,

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell1"];
    [cell.deleteButton setTag:indexPath.row];
    [cell.deleteButton add target:@selector(deleteButtonTapped:) for state : UIControlStateTouchupinside];
    return cell;
}
```

Now, you can get the index of row from `deleteButtomTapped:`.

```
- (IBAction)deleteButtonTapped:(UIButton*)sender {

    [self.arrPeopleDetail  removeObjectAtIndex:sender.tag];
    [self.detailTable reloadData];
}
```

If you use `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths withRowAnimation:` instead of `reloadData`, you will have deletion animation.

Comment: u missed the main line **deleteButtonTapped** in cell for Row at index

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I assumed that the button's target is set via xib or storyboard, because the method's return type is `IBAction`.

Comment: trick, when I am setting the button's tag an error is coming, it's showing that, "Property 'deleteButton' is not found on object of type UITableViewCell".

Comment: @Tirthendu What is the name of button? You have to use the name instead of `deleteButton`

Comment: just u assign the property of **deletebuttion** in tablecellclass, then it working fine

Comment: I used the name of my button as deletButtonTapped.

Comment: and i haven't taken a class named as tablecellclass. @Anbu.Karthik

Answer (score 0):

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` function of Tableview, set the `tag` property for the delete button. 
`<DELETE_BUTTON>.tag = indexPath.row`.
Then in delete function, you will get the index clicked.
Remove the object in that index and reload the table.

```
- (IBAction)deleteButtonTapped:(id)sender {
int index = [sender tag];
[self.arrPeopleDetail removeObjectAtIndex:index];
[self.detailTable reloadData];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell  = [tblObj dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"myCell"];

    if (cell==nil)
    {
      NSArray *arr = [[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"myCell" owner:self
                                                options:nil];
        cell = [arr objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    UILabel *lbl1 = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
    lbl1.text = [arr1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


    UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:2];
    btn.tag = indexPath.row;

    [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(btnPress:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    return cell;
}

-(IBAction)btnPress:(UIButton *)btn
{
    [arr1 removeObjectAtIndex:btn.tag];

    NSIndexPath *indexPath=[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:btn.tag inSection:0];
    [tblObj beginUpdates];
    [tblObj deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    [tblObj endUpdates];
    [tblObj reloadData];

}
```